Causality and Free-Will
Is free-will necessary to define the concept of causality? Let A and B be two events such that
P(A | B) != P(A)
Where the first term is the conditioned probability that A occurs given B, it's clear that if the previous condition holds, the two events are correlated with each other.
Of course, this is not sufficient to infer that event B is the cause of event A, if I hold a coin in my left or right hand, and ask you to guess which hand is holding the coin, the fact that the coin is in my right hand is independent of the fact that you guessed "left", even tough
1 = P(Right Coin | Left Empty) != P(Right Coin).
However, suppose that the information about the coin being in either hand is completely unknowable, you then pick "left" and the hand is empty, then it means that the coin is in the right hand with probability 1/2, but suppose that everytime you choose the empty hand, the other hand always contains a coin, the only logical conclusion is that your act of choosing the empty hand is the cause of the coin appearing in the other hand.
If this wasn't the case, you would sometimes observe that both hands are empty, precisely because the information about the coin being in either hand is unknowable. However, if you were not free in choosing the hand to begin with, it's easy to see how this odd behaviour reduces to a simple correlation as the first example, so in a sense this shows that:
Absence of Free Will --> Absence of causality
Is there some truth to this statement?

Please note that this site is not intended to present one's own independent thoughts in form of a new approach. To see which kind of questions and answers are expected and to inform oneself about this site, please see https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour


Where the first term is the conditioned probability that A occurs given B. == But the vertical bar denotes disjunction. I think perhaps you meant to say, P(B->A)!=P(A).


@MissUnderstands the described meaning is standard for probabilities. Read "the probability of measuring A after measuring B does not equal the prior probability of A after measuring initial conditions similar except for having not yet measured B or not-B"

@davyz2 the answer to your question can be found in the same reading. A probability is a fact about two sets of measurements. Treating it as an intrinsic characteristic will generate errors.

Re your beginning "Where the first term is the conditioned probability that A occurs given B, it's clear that if the previous condition holds, the two events are correlated with each other.", it already seems problematic in the sense of the usual (linear) correlation in stats...

"The only logical conclusion is that your act of choosing is the cause", no it is not. Correlation does not imply causation with or without choosing. And if causation could not exist without free will then it could not exist in a universe without living beings. Which this universe has been in its early stages and the living beings were caused by it nonetheless. All you need for causation is a connecting physical law of the right sort, it can be completely deterministic.

I don’t understand how you are using "causality" here. Causal relationships do lead to correlations, so it’s not clear how you make the leap from "reduces to just correlation" to "absence of causality". Can you please clarify that?

"the only logical conclusion is that your act of choosing the empty hand is the cause of the coin appearing in the other hand." That is, if we forget everything we know about coins, notably that coins don't spontaneously appear in people's hands. For anyone who is not a toddler and has acquired a sense of object permanence, it does not follow logically from a long series of picking the empty hand that it's their decision that moves the coin to the other hand.

Absence of free will does not imply absence of causality.
In fact, a common conception of determinism known as causal determinism posits that everything is part of a "causal chain." Under this view, our own "deliberations, choices, and actions" are themselves caused (and determined) by the past, and further cause and determine later effects.

In a universe which is "causally deterministic" as you describe, there would be no meaning to causality, there would be only statistical correlation between events, it would be meaningless to say that an action has "caused" another one, every non-trivial conditional probability would amount to a simple correlation, right?

I don't see why you suggest that, @Davyz2.  Perhaps you're using an unconventional definition of "cause" and "causality"?  It is not usual for me to limit causation to acts of will.

Clearly not. As a simple counter-example, radiation from the Sun causes parts of Earth to get warmer during the day. The Sun is not an intentional being, we do not consider it to have free will. So this is a cause and effect without free will being involved.
Even if we confine discussion to actions of people, we don't need free will. If you accidentally drop a glass, it will cause the contents to spill on the floor. But you didn't drop the glass intentionally (although you presumably picked it up deliberately, so there's free will in the chain of events).

Nah, the sun is intentional, it's just a 3 year old who really likes fusion. Yay fusion! Do again! Yay! Do again! Yay!

@gs Right, like Trelane

A coherent statistical account of causality is given in Judea Pearl's book, Causality.
I would not say you're right - free will is unnecessary to causation. But there is a slight kernel of truth to what you're saying, and it's this. Causality is about what would follow at a later time, if some initial condition is set to be different from what it actually was. And free will is the claim that you could have chosen differently; your choice (an initial condition) is something you can freely set to be different.
So it is very natural to speak of what was caused by a person's decisions, which involves saying things like, "had I taken I-95 I would have regretted it." Taking I-95 would have caused regret, and therefore not taking I-95 prevented the regret. To talk about causation we need to speak of a difference between the two initial conditions - taking I-95 or not taking it - leading to a difference between the two final conditions - regretting, or not regretting, the path taken. To do this we need to have some notion that the initial choice could vary.
It is somewhat less natural to speak this way about mindless physical events such as a boulder rolling down a hill and crushing someone's house. "If the boulder had rolled ten feet to the left, it would have missed my house." It's a reasonable statement - but on the other hand the boulder could not have rolled ten feet to the left, because its path was fully dictated by the laws of physics; it could only have gone exactly where it went. We would like to be able to say that the rolling boulder indeed caused the person's house to be crushed. But to justify this claim we need to be able to talk about a difference in the initial conditions - a difference in the path of the boulder, leading to a different outcome. And since the boulder definitely has no free will, how can we talk about such differences?
The answer given by Pearl is that we need to first build a causal model. This, generally speaking, involves a directed acyclic graph where events higher in the graph cause - and temporally precede - events lower in the graph. So there would be a sequence of events, like: Base of boulder eroded over thousands of years + Mild earthquake -> Boulder toppled to the right -> Boulder struck house.
Then, to trace causation from B to A, we don't ask P(A=a | B=b). Instead, we ask P(A=a | do(B=b)). This means that in the causal graph, we set the variable B to the value b, severing all the parents of B in the graph, and then trace the consequences down to A. This is in contrast to P(A=a | B=b), which represents observing that B has the value b, and can sometimes involve inferences propagating upwards and sideways in the graph rather than just downwards. P(A=a | B=b) will in general give different numbers from P(A=a | do(B=b)).
For the boulder, let B = the direction the boulder toppled, and A = how close the boulder came to the house. If we set up an initial condition where the boulder toppled slightly more to the left - even though physics does not, technically, allow for that - and then traced the consequences of that in our model, our model says it would have missed the house. This is what lets us say that the direction the boulder fell caused the destruction of the house.
We don't need to assign free will to the boulder. We simply need a model that draws arrows between events, and the ability to edit the model (set B to a value) and trace the downstream consequences within the model. We're tracing consequences as if the boulder had been free to topple in different initial directions - even though it wasn't.
In free will, the above "as if" is supposed to be actual fact somehow, for the choices of human beings. But we don't need this assumption to trace causation, because a model based on "as ifs" is enough.

The reasoning in your question is flawed:

you then pick "left" and the hand is empty, then it means that the coin is in the right hand with probability 1/2

No, if you see that the left hand is empty, then the coin is in the right hand with probability 1: it's guaranteed to be in the right hand. It's only 1/2 before you see which hand the coin is in.

suppose that every time you choose the empty hand, the other hand always contains a coin, the only logical conclusion is that your act of choosing the empty hand is the cause of the coin appearing in the other hand

Not quite. There is firstly a statistical test needed to reject the chance that this just happens randomly (with some probability). If that is overcome, we still have to look for confounding variables that affect which option you choose and which hand the coin is in, as well as inverse correlation. For example, maybe the person holding their hands out is intentionally holding the empty hand with a slightly looser grip, to make you think the coin is in the empty hand, and thus consistently choose that hand.
This type of causation would also come with an added burden of not making much sense with how we understand the laws of physics. So we need to be super extra sure that such causation did actually happen, and it wasn't actually just some complex trickery or something.
Although these are things that can be resolved, in theory, to conclude causation.

If this wasn't the case, you would sometimes observe that both hands are empty, precisely because the information about the coin being in either hand is unknowable.

I can't make sense of which "this" you're talking about here. But in any case, what you're saying sounds incorrect. As long as the probabilities add up to 100%, that necessarily covers all possibilities. If there's a chance of both hands being empty, then the probability of at least one hand must be less than 50%.

However, if you were not free in choosing the hand to begin with, it's easy to see how this odd behaviour reduces to a simple correlation as the first example

I don't see how this follows from what you said before (even putting aside the issues with that).
At no point did you mention what determines your choice and whether that's "free", and that doesn't seem to have anything to do with what happens after that choice, which is what you were focusing on before that.
But note that we can't, strictly speaking, definitively, and with complete certainty, "prove" causation. The best we can do is find strong correlations, eliminate confounding variables, etc., as mentioned above, to make causation the most reasonable conclusion. But this doesn't say much about free will.
The underlying issue: probability doesn't "exist"
The underlying issue is that your argument seems to depend on probability existing fundamentally in nature. That us saying there's a 50% probability of each hand means it has a partial existence in both hands at the same time, and it only begins to exist concretely when one hand is opened.
This is not a common view, and it's not what people typically mean when they talk about probabilities.
It would generally be accepted that the coin is definitely already in one of the hands. The 50% probability only represents our knowledge, and a change in probability just means we know different things. When we don't know which hand it's in, we assign a 50% probability to each hand. When we do know which hand it's in, we assign a 100% probability to the hand it's in (or maybe less if you want to account for uncertainty about perception). But the coin is already in whichever hand in both cases. The only thing that's different is our knowledge of that.
* This is putting aside quantum mechanics and the question of whether probabilities are "fundamental" there.
Choice has causal power (and that's not a problem)
Human choices have much more directly causal effects. Why speculate about whether you choosing a hand causes the coin to be in one hand or the other, when one can simply say choosing a hand causes that hand to be opened. Well, maybe both would be opened, but the point is that there is much more direct causes to choices, which aren't just hypothetical - we've done the statistical tests described above, and eliminated confounding variables, to reasonably infer causation.
But this is not at all a problem for people who reject (libertarian) free will, because one can just say that one's choices/actions are themselves determined by other things (i.e. they aren't "free", which I argue is not something we'd want in any case, but choice may still have causal power).
Consciousness and choice having a lack of causal power seems to be a fringe view, limited mostly to epiphenomenalism. Others disagree about what consciousness is and whether choice is "free", but tend to agree that it can have causal effects on other things.

Through my reflections on free will, I've concluded that it is not an absolute concept, but rather a dynamic process dependent on our awareness and the situation we find ourselves in. The central question I started with was whether we truly have full control over our choices, and I realized that our decisions are not always fully independent. What we call free will is often the result of our ability to reflect and be conscious of our actions.
Free Will as a Dynamic Process
Reflecting on what influences our choices, I noticed that our decisions are often shaped by external factors like emotions, culture, and societal pressures. Although we may make conscious decisions, we don't always have full control over what influences us. For instance, our emotions can cloud rational thinking, and in stressful situations, we may make choices that seem free, but in reality, they are driven by impulses that we don't fully control.
The Role of Awareness
However, when we become more aware of our thoughts and emotions, our free will seems to become more "autonomous." The better we understand why we make certain choices, the easier it is to act in a way that aligns with our values. This led me to conclude that free will depends more on our awareness than on some unchanging trait.
Scientific and Philosophical Arguments
From a scientific standpoint, research into neurobiology shows that the decisions we make often have their origin in brain activity before we even become conscious of them. This suggests that our actions are not entirely controlled by our awareness but rather by unconscious processes in the brain. On the other hand, philosophers argue that the way we perceive our choices is just as important. We feel free when we can reflect on our decisions and understand their impact on our lives.
Summary
As I concluded, free will is not static but dependent on our awareness and circumstances. The more we are aware of our motivations and the influences acting on us, the greater our ability to make truly free decisions. However, in situations where we lack full awareness or are under external influence, our free will is limited. In this sense, free will is a process we can shape, but we don't always have full control over it.

Free will is not required for causality. It is the other way around. Causality is required for free will.
Causality is about how causes determine their effects.
Free will is about generating new causes to get desired effects.
